# What part of speech is "handsome" in the following sentence

Tags: parts-of-speech

What part of speech is **handsome** in the sentence:

> The bridegroom looked so handsome.

Answer (score 2):

**Handsome** is an *adjective* in this sentence:

> The bridegroom looked so handsome.
>
> 1. *Adj.* having an attractive, well-proportioned, and imposing appearance suggestive of health and strength; good-looking
>
>    > https://www.thefreedictionary.com/handsome

It is an adjective and describes the subject "the bridegroom". What is tricking you is that "looked" here is a **linking verb**, which are used to describe the state of being of the subject of a clause. (Unlike action verbs, which describe the action of the subject.) See [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/linking+verb).

Comment: Doesn't handsome describe about the verb of the sentence can't it be considered as an adverb

Comment: No, it is an adjective and describes the subject "the bridegroom". What is tricking you is that "looks" here is a **linking verb**, which are used to describe the state of being of the subject of a clause. (Unlike action verbs, which describe the action of the subject.) See https://www.thefreedictionary.com/linking+verb

Answer (score 2):

It's an adjective and not an adverb because it's not modifying the action of looking. So for instance, in the sentence "He looked thoroughly around the room," "thoroughly" is an adverb because it is describing how the action occurred.  In your sentence, "handsome" is not modifying how the "looking" occurred but "the bridegroom."  The fact that "look" can both indicate an action (He looked around) and effectively be an equal signs (i.e. a linking verb) may be the stumbling block here.

Comment: A small point @user338477. The AdjP "so handsome" isn't a modifier. Predicatives are complements, not modifiers. In the OP's example, the AdjP refers to "bridegroom", of course, but its function is that of complement of "look".

Comment: Point taken, though I wasn't using "modify" in the sense of syntactic theory but in a layman's sense, since the person who posed the question didn't strike me as having a background in theoretical linguistics. If I'm wrong, then I'll clarify my last sentence to indicate that the confusion arises from "look" being both unergative and perhaps a functional verb (i.e. the linking verb use of "look" is probably not base generated in VP, but in a functional projection).